# Regex match anything up to word - without non-greedy operators

Tags: c#, regex

I want to match anything up to a specific word (e.g., the closing comment in C `*/`), however, due to performance reasons I don't want to make use of non-greedy operators.

E.g., to match C comments: `/\*.*?\*/` is too slow for my files. Is there any possibility to improve performance?

Comment: Performance of using greedy vs. nongreedy may depend on the length of the comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure, use [*unrolling-the-loop* technique](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop):

```
/\*[^*]*(?:\*(?!/)[^*]*)*\*/
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%2F%5C*%5B%5E*%5D*(%3F%3A%5C*(%3F!%2F)%5B%5E*%5D*)*%5C*%2F&i=%2F*%0D%0A*%20Comment%0D%0A*%20here%0D%0A*%2F)

> The unrolling the loop technique is based on the hypothesis that in most case, you kown in a repeteated alternation, which case should be the most usual and which one is exceptional. We will called the first one, the normal case and the second one, the special case. The general syntax of the unrolling the loop technique could then be written as:
>
> `normal* ( special normal* )*`
>
> Which could means something like, match the normal case, if you find a special case, matched it than match the normal case again. You notice that part of this syntax could potentialy lead to a super-linear match. To avoid a neverending match to append, the following rules shoud be carefully applied:
>
> - the start of the special case and the normal case must be mutually exclusive
> - special must always match at least one character
> - the special expression must be atomic: be careful to the fact that `( special normal* )*` could be reduced to `(special)*`, which if special is `special*`, this became similar to `(a*)*` which is a undeterministic expression.

C# pattern declaration (using a verbatim string literal):

```
var pattern = @"/\*[^*]*(?:\*(?!/)[^*]*)*\*/";
```

The regex breakdown:

- `/\*` - literal `/*`
- `[^*]*` - 0 or more character other than `*`
- `(?:\*(?!/)[^*]*)*` - 0 or more sequences of...

  - `\*(?!/)` - a literal `*` not followed by `/`
  - `[^*]*` -  0 or more character other than `*`
- `\*/` - literal `*/`

Here is a graph showing how efficient the 3 potentially identical regexps are (tested at [regexhero.net](http://regexhero.net/tester)*):

[image]

* Tested against `/* Comment
* Typical
* Comment
*/`

Comment: Cool. Didn't know about unrolling-the-loop. Thx. +1 for that.

Comment: For the "unrolling-the-loop technique" ... +1

Comment: Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: @D.R.: Always glad to help. Thank you for a great question!

Comment: @stribizhev: After reading "Mastering Regular Expressions" I've found that the version `/\*[^*]*\*+([^/*][^*]*\*+)*/` is another 3.5% faster (according to RegexHero.net).

Comment: Yes, it is a further level of unrolling since this expression is specific for 2-character delimiters sharing a common character. I would even call it a customized unrolled regex. Very good job.

Comment: Just note that [`/\*([^*]*(?:\*(?!/)[^*]*)*)\*/`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%2f%5c*(%5b%5e*%5d*(%3f%3a%5c*(%3f!%2f)%5b%5e*%5d*)*)%5c*%2f&i=%2f*%0d%0a*+Comment%0d%0a*+here%0d%0a*%2f) will capture the inner part of the comment without `*` from the trailing delimiter, and yours above expression used like [`/\*([^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*)/`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%2f%5c*(%5b%5e*%5d*%5c*%2b(%3f%3a%5b%5e%2f*%5d%5b%5e*%5d*%5c*%2b)*)%2f&i=%2f*%0d%0a*+Comment%0d%0a*+here%0d%0a*%2f) will grab that last `*`. So, these expressions have different flexibility.

Comment: You should probably cite Jeffrey Friedl (and his most excellent book: "[Mastering Regular Expressions](https://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124)") in this (otherwise excellent) answer, as he is the inventor of this very handy technique. In fact, solving this C comment expression problem is what led him to discover his unrolling-the-loop technique in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

[`/\*(?:[^*]|\*(?!/))*\*/`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%2f%5c*(%3f%3a%5b%5e*%5d%7c%5c*(%3f!%2f))*%5c*%2f&i=%2f*%0d%0a*+Comment%0d%0a*+here%0d%0a**%2f)

I don't know whether it is faster than stribizhev's answer.

Comment: This `/\*(?:[^*]|\*[^/])*\*/` regex won't match [this comment](https://regex101.com/r/lK9yE7/1) ending in `**/` due to the `[^/]` negated character class after ``\*``. So, even if it is faster, it is just different in what it can match. However, it requires much more steps to return a valid match than unrolling-the-loop regex because of alternation.

Comment: @stribizhev Indeed. Your right. I changed my sample.

Comment: Good, now they are identical in what they match, but alternation still requires much more backtracking in comparison with unrolled version.

Comment: @stribizhev Yes I gave you a +1 for that technique.