# JavaScript regular expression to find pattern in "commented" code

Tags: javascript, regex, comments

I have JavaScript snippets that are stored in strings. I need to look at the strings, determine if they contain specific code "special[i].code" for example.

I only care if specific code is NOT commented out. If it finds code that is not commented, I need to return a true value, or just the position.

Example snippets that are stored in a string.

```
function someFunction() {
    special[i].code
}
RegEx returns: True (Contains uncommitted occurrence)

function someFunction() {
    // special[i].code
}
RegEx returns: False (Occurrence commented out)

function someFunction() {
    /* 
    special[i].code
    morecode();
    */
}
RegEx returns: False (Occurrence commented out)

function someFunction() {
    /* special[i].code */
    special[i].code
}
RegEx returns: True (Contains uncommitted occurrence)
```

I don't know regular expressions enough to build a proper expression. Trying to use editors, but because // and /* are themselves reserved characters, even when I escape them, I can't get it to detect properly. Even when I try to do something like //\ or //*.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: If you don't know Regex enough to build an expression, I'd recommend you to learn. You can start here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ you can also test stuff here: https://regex101.com/ . A quick note about escaping: you need to use double backslash '\\' to escape between double quotes, otherwise just use simple '\'.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/dH8pE2/1

Comment: Search - you will find. On regex101, you can get the JS code on the code generator page

Comment: I don't think beginners will grasp parsing C style comments parsing using regex. You can study regex for about a year then come back here with an attempt. There is a regex on SO I've posted to do that, but can't find where it is. What it would do is basically find all comments and non-comments. You can stick your code literals in the non-comment part and it would work. If you need it I could repost it here, but suggest you search.

Comment: Here you are: [`/\/\*[^*]*\*+([^\/*][^*]*\*+)*\//g`](https://regex101.com/r/aY8tV0/1) (see [my C# answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33895861/3832970)). Now it is up to you to think of a way to match them not inside C strings (hint: again, an unroll-the-loop approach will help).

Comment: My go-to site for everything regex is [RegExr](http://regexr.com/). It is user friendly and great for practice and testing.

Comment: @stribizhev - Your regex tends to ignore single line comments `//` and ignores string's. Probably going to miss this _special code_ var A = ' `/* ';special[i].code = 'a';var B = ' */` ';

Comment: @sln: That regex was not written to match single line comments. It only matches multiline ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this.
(*note- this is specific to JavaScript*)

The predicament with matching comments is you have to match strings as well
since comment parts can be embedded in strings.

Given that you end up matching comments, strings, non-comments *and* within
the non-comments, you'd want to match your *special code*.

It probably could be the case where you would like to single match everything
up until it finds your *special code*. Then you would have a single match
resulting in TRUE/FALSE.

You would think that, and a regex could be set up to do that...
*BUT* this would lead to a complexity issue if a match is not found.

So, what ends up happening is that you have to sit in a loop, getting all the
parts until there are no more matches, *OR*, it finds the special code you're
looking for, where then you have the option to break out.
Not sure about JS, but if you can't sit in a loop, just find all in one go,
then check the capture buffer 3 array (or, every third one if its one big
array).

In this regex, the special code (if found) will always be in group 3.
So, you only have to check if group 3 is not NULL, set a flag, then break out of the loop.

When done, return appropriate response based of if the *flag* was set.

This is the compressed and delimited `/../` regex:

```
/(\/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^\/*][^*]*\*+)*\/|\/\/[^\n]*(?:\n|$))|("[^"\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*'|(?!special\[i\]\.code)[\S\s](?:(?!special\[i\]\.code)[^\/"'])*)|(special\[i\]\.code)/
```

This is the *Raw* regex in readable format (with comments):

```
    (                                # (1 start), Comments 
         /\*                              # Start /* .. */ comment
         [^*]* \*+
         (?: [^/*] [^*]* \*+ )*
         /                                # End /* .. */ comment
      |  
         //  [^\n]*                       # Start // comment
         (?: \n | $ )                     # End // comment
    )                                # (1 end)
 |                                 # OR,
    (                                # (2 start), Non - comments 
         "
         [^"\\]*                          # Double quoted text
         (?: \\ [\S\s] [^"\\]* )*
         "
      |  
         '
         [^'\\]*                          # Single quoted text
         (?: \\ [\S\s] [^'\\]* )*
         ' 
      |  
         (?! special\[i\]\.code )         # This is to blow by any non-comment '/' char or any unbalanced quotes (technically a code error)
         [\S\s]                        
                                          # Any other char, but not these special tokens.
                                          # Chars which doesn't start a comment or string
         (?:                              # But not special tokens
              (?! special\[i\]\.code )
              [^/"'] 
         )*
    )                                # (2 end)
 |                                 # OR,
    (                                # (3 start), Special Tokens
         special\[i\]\.code                    
    )                                # (3 end)
```

Here are some examples with corresponding matches:

RegEx returns: True (Contains uncommitted occurrence)

```
function someFunction() {
    special[i].code
}

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 31 ) 
function someFunction() {

 **  Grp 1 -  NULL 
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 0 , len 31 ) 
function someFunction() {

 **  Grp 3 -  NULL 

-------------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 31 , len 15 ) 
special[i].code  
 **  Grp 1 -  NULL 
 **  Grp 2 -  NULL 
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 31 , len 15 ) 
special[i].code
```

*can break here since group 3 is not NULL*

---

RegEx returns: True (Contains uncommitted occurrence)

```
function someFunction() {
    /* special[i].code */
    special[i].code
}

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 31 ) 
function someFunction() {

 **  Grp 1 -  NULL 
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 0 , len 31 ) 
function someFunction() {

 **  Grp 3 -  NULL 

-------------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 31 , len 21 ) 
/* special[i].code */  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 31 , len 21 ) 
/* special[i].code */  
 **  Grp 2 -  NULL 
 **  Grp 3 -  NULL 

-------------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 52 , len 6 ) 


 **  Grp 1 -  NULL 
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 52 , len 6 ) 


 **  Grp 3 -  NULL 

-------------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 58 , len 15 ) 
special[i].code  
 **  Grp 1 -  NULL 
 **  Grp 2 -  NULL 
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 58 , len 15 ) 
special[i].code
```

*can break here since group 3 is not NULL*

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and the breakdown of the expression!

Comment: @Nick - You're welcome!  I can't take credit though. This regex was adapted from someone else's regex originally posted on a Perl newsgroup about 10 years ago. I've made several versions of it for different languages.